# Convert svg-element to image

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, export

i have a html svg element (not canvas) and have to save the content to a image file (png or jpg).

Is there any solution for this?

canvas.toDataURL() didn't work, because it's a svg element.

example:

```
<svg:svg id ="svg">
         <svg:svg width="{width}" height="{height}">
            <svg:circle cx="{cx}" cy="{cy}" r="{radius}" id="circ" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
            <svg:text x="{tposW}" y="30" line="0" text-anchor="middle">{VORNAME}</svg:text>
            <svg:text x="{tposW}" y="44" line="1" text-anchor="middle">{NAME}</svg:text>
            <svg:text x="{tposW}" y="58" line="2" text-anchor="middle">{GEB}</svg:text>
        </svg:svg>
</svg:svg>
```

Please post only solutions without using jQuery.

Comment: Aslo you could use the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-dataurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the canvg JavaScript library to render the SVG image using Canvas: 
http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

and then use the `canvas.toDataURL()`